# Instr function, finding the entire number, so 12 will not return true for 1

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to search a cell for numbers that may have been input. 
So B2's value is 12. When using Instr it will find 1,2 and 12. Is there a way for it to return only 12? Here is the code I am currently using for it, which if I only used 1-9 would be fine however I need more options.

```
Sub PRTLookup()
Dim WsP As Worksheet
Dim PRTval As String
Dim MonCt As Long, DayCT As Long

Set WsP = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PT")

For MonCt = 2 To 46 Step 4
    For DayCT = 2 To 32
         CelVal = Cells(MonCt, DayCT)
            If IsNumeric(CelVal) Then
                For x = 1 To 26
                    If InStr(Cells(MonCt, DayCT).Text, x) Then PRTval = PRTval + WsP.Cells(x, 1).Value
                Next
                Cells(MonCt, DayCT).Value = PRTval
                PRTval = Empty
            End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

This is the Final code that worked for me:

```
Dim myarr() as string
Dim num as Variant

For MonCt = 2 To 46 Step 4
    For DayCT = 2 To 32
        Celval = Cells(MonCt, DayCT)
        myarr = Split(Celval, ",")
            For Each num In myarr
                PRTval = PRTval & " " & WsP.Cells(num, 1).Text
            Next num
        Cells(MonCt, DayCT).Value = PRTval
        PRTval = Empty
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Could your cells have multiple numbers? How would that be formatted?

Comment: Where did `CelVal` get its value?

Comment: @Trincot, a cell value can have multiple numbers. the numbers will be input like 1,4,6,13 etc. depending on what they want from WsP worksheet.       CelVal didn't get copied into the code for whatever reason, I edited it to add it in though.

Comment: Do realise that `IsNumeric(CelVal)` will not be True when you have such a comma-separated list. It will be a string, and the `If` block will not be entered.

Comment: What kind of values are in `WsP.Cells(x, 1).Value`? Strings? Numbers?

Comment: I suppose I could have them entered with spaces and then add the comma when I set PRTval. `WsP.cells(x,1).value` are strings. Specifically they will be a description of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite understanding your question but here are my thoughts:

You can first split the input string by comma (saving it into an array), then iterate through each number inside that array and checking if it contains the value:

```
Dim myarr() as String  
Dim num as String 
myarr = Split(inputLine, ",")
For each num in myarr
    ......
Next num
```

Comment: This worked for me although I had to change num to a variant. I updated the question with the way my code ended up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- The test `IsNumeric` will not yield `True` when the content is a comma-separated list, in which case it will have the String data type.
- The variable `PRTVal` is declared as a string, but you use the `+` operator on it. That should be `&`.

You can use `Split` to split a string by the comma delimiter, and then you can loop over the parts.

Here is the part to adapt:

```
Dim nums As String
Dim str As Variant
' ... etc ...

If IsNumeric(Replace(Replace(CelVal, ",", ""), " ", "")) Then
    PRTval = ""
    nums = Split(CelVal, ",")
    For Each str In nums
        x = CInt(str)
        If x >= 1 And x <= 26 Then PRTval = PRTval & ", " & WsP.Cells(x, 1).Value
    Next
    Cells(MonCt, DayCT).Value = Mid(PRTval, 3) ' skip first ", "
End If
```

Comment: I tried this and I kept coming up with "For each may iterate" errors. I used @cullan's suggestion and that worked for me. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: OK, the error may be due to the data type of `str`: if you declare it as `Variant` it might resolve it. Anyway,  good to hear you got it working with cullan's solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can look for a number first and then check whether the next character is a number too. So you iterate as long as there is no more number.

UPDATE:
I would do something like this:

```
For i = 1 To Len(myString)
    j = 0
    If IsNumeric(Mid(myString, i, 1)) Then
        Do While IsNumeric(Mid(myString, i, 1 + j)) And i + j <= Len(myString)
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        output = Mid(myString, i, j)
        MsgBox output
    End If
    i = i + j
Next i
```

Comment: Do you know how I could check the what the next character is? Would it be something like this; `if InStr(Cells(MonCt, DayCT).Text, x) Then  i = InStr(Cells(MonCt, DayCT).Text, x) + 1   if Isnumeric(i) then` the rest of my code?

Comment: I would rather do something like this:

Comment: For i = 1 To Len(myStr)
        j = 0
        If IsNumeric(Mid(myStr, i, 1)) Then
            Do While IsNumeric(Mid(myStr, i, 1 + j)) And i + j <= Len(myStr)
                j = j + 1
            Loop
            output = Mid(myStr, i, j)
            MsgBox output
        End If
        i = i + j
    Next i